# An easy integration

Tags: integration

Find the area under the function $y=(x-1)(x-2)(x-3)$ between $1<x<3.$

My attempt:
We need to find the value of 
$$\int^3_1(x-1)(x-2)(x-3)dx$$

$$\int(x-1)(x-2)(x-3)dx=\int x^3-6x^2+11x-6=\frac{x^4}{4}-2x^3+\frac{11x^2}{2}-6x$$
Now, substitute 1 and 3 into the expression gives the answer: 
$$\left(\frac{3^4}{4}-2\cdot 3^3+\frac{11\cdot 3^2}{2}-6\cdot 3\right)-\left(\frac{1^4}{4}-2\cdot 1^3+\frac{11\cdot 1^2}{2}-6\cdot 1\right)=0$$
But on the book it says the answer is $-\frac{1}{2}$.

Where did I get wrong?

Note: please explain each step throughly since I just step into integration.

Comment: Put $u = x-2$. The integral becomes $\int_{-1}^1 (u+1)u(u-1) \, du $. Since the integrand is an odd function, the integral has value 0.

Comment: Does the question just say "area under $y=(x-1)(x-2)(x-3)$" without mentioning $1$ and $3$?

Comment: @GEdgar I see what you are suggesting, but if that were the case, shouldn't the correct answer be $+\frac{1}{2}$?

Comment: If we just don't know what it says, then we cannot answer.

Comment: What is an odd function?

Comment: @abc... An odd function is a function $f$ that has the property that $f(-x) = -f(x)$ for all $x$ in its domain.

Comment: I think the textbook have got the wrong answer. Thanks to all of you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your integration steps are not wrong at all. I think the textbook has the wrong answer. I used WolframAlpha to calculate the integration and the numerical answer was 0, which agrees to your solution.

https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+(x-1)(x-2)(x-3)+from+1+to+3

Answer (score 2):

The textbook answer is bizarre.  The area bounded by the curve and the $x$-axis between $x = 1$ and $2$ is $\frac14$, while the area between $x = 2$ and $3$ is $-\frac14$, but I don't see how one can legitimately add those together and get $-\frac12$.

Comment: Maybe like the circle centered in 0 has the aera zero but the teacher may ask for the surface....it seems they added both surfaces in absolute value

Comment: @Isham: Yeah, but then the final answer is *negative*?!  It's just weird.

Comment: He added absolute value I guess